# How to switch user entered search string between RegEx and plain Text

Tags: c#, regex

I want to give the user the possibility to search in some data.
The user enters his search string in a textbox.
The more advanced users should be able to enter not only plain text but also regular expression for a better search result (and set a checkbox to tell us, he has entered a regex)

I'm currently having this implementation, which treats each input as regex.

```
string filter = sometextbox.Text;
Regex rgx = new Regex(filter);
for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    if (rgx.IsMatch(data[i].Content))
    {
        // Found it, preset it to the user
        break;
    }
}
```

**How can I Change between treating the input as regex or as plain text?**

Comment: You cannot check if a string "[a]" is a regex pattern or a plain text. You need a checkbox "Regex mode". If checked, use a regex for the input pattern. If not, use a simple `string.Contains`,etc.

Comment: @stribizhev I don't wanna detect, if the user has entered a regex or simple text. He should set a checkbox to identify a regex. (Which i wrote in the question...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string filter = sometextbox.Text;
Regex rgx = new Regex(filter);
bool IsRegEx = RegExCheckBox.Checked;

List<string> Matches = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    if (IsRegEx && rgx.IsMatch(data[i].Content))
        Matches.Add(data[i].Content);
    else if (!IsRegEx && data[i].Content.ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())) 
        Matches.Add(data[i].Content);
}

//Do something with your list of Matches
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope, I understood your question right.
I understood that you want to turn on/off regex search using a CheckBox control, all your are going to do is to check the state of the CheckBox and determine the code you are going to use to do the search.

```
string filter = sometextbox.Text;
if(RegexCheckBox.IsChecked)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex(filter);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        if (rgx.IsMatch(data[i].Content))
        {
            // Found it, preset it to the user
            break;
        }
    }   
}
else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
    {
        if(data[i] == filter)
        {
            //found it, present it to the user
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exacly what I was looking for. And it is so simple. I was thinking much to complicated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good answer, but if data[i] doesn't EXACTLY match the entered text, this won't work.  Try using contains like in my answer so that users can search for partial patterns (much more efficient for them).